# Android-how to check data download finished or not in second activity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am downloading product information (it takes some time to download) in mainactivity which I am going to display in secondactivity. If user goes to secondactivity before the downloading the data,it should show progressbar then check the download has been finished or not. Then it should show the products in secondactivity.

How should I check the download has been finished or not in secondactivity thats happening in mainactivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      
   LoadProducts();//downloads data from server.      
   gridLayoutProductButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v){
     SecondActivity.ProductModelList = MainActivity.productarray;
     Intent secondIntent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(),SecondActivity.class);
     secondIntent.putExtra("layout_code", 1);
     secondIntent.putExtra("layouttype",viewtype);
     secondIntent.putExtra("title", title);                       
     itemView.getContext().startActivity(secondIntent);
     }
   });
  }
}
```

My second activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    TextView pagetitle=findViewById(R.id.pagetitletxt);
    pleasewaittxt=findViewById(R.id.pleasewaittxt);
    productloading=findViewById(R.id.loadingproductpageprogress);
    gridView = findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        
    productloading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    pleasewaittxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    GridProductLayoutAdapter gridProductLayoutAdapter = new GridProductLayoutAdapter(ProductModelList);
    gridView.setAdapter(gridProductLayoutAdapter);
  }
}
```

I know my logic is wrong, but I want to download data in mainactivity and display in secondactivity.
I don't want to prevent users from entering secondactivity until the download is complete.
How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

If you need that download to continue while you can leave the activity, you should do it in a Service. Otherwise, the second you leave the First Activity, it becomes subject to being killed (and your download along with it).

Then your second Activity can bind to that service and track the same information as the First Activity.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: after reading the link that you gave me and trying sometime. I came to know that android deprecated background services,Intentservices and jobintentservices. now i dont know what I should do. Can you help and guide me to solve my issue.

Comment: Fortunately you don't need a background service, intent service, or job intent service - you just need to bind to a service. Or checkout out WorkManager as the deprecation notice on those other classes indicate.

Comment: what do you mean I just need to bind to a service.i still need to startservice in the background and not in the foreground right?.can you explain me more with the code example

Comment: Did you read the documenation link I provided? It explains binding to a service. Here is the direct link: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#CreatingBoundService